# Sending NSNumber to another class method - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having trouble sending over an `NSInteger` to another class.  Here is what I am doing.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSInteger tag = cell.tag;
    impact* myScript = [[impact alloc] init];
    [myScript startProcess:tag];
}
```

Here I am sending a `NSInteger` to the impact's `startProcess` method.  The issue is when sending it over I get the following error:

```
No visible @interface for 'impact' declares the selector 'startProcess:'
```

But the thing is I am defining the `startProcess` method.

Here is the `impact.h` file:

```
-(NSInteger *)startProcess;
```

Here is the `impact.m` file:

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)startProcess:(NSInteger **)number {
    [UITableView reloadData];

}
```

So to recap, I am trying to send over an `NSInteger` to another class's method and than reload the entire table.  Now sure why I am getting this error though.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you will notice two main problems:

1. The declaration in the header file does not match the implementation in the implementation file. The basic format of a method is `- (ReturnType)methodName:(<ParamType>)paramName;` In the header you are defining a method that takes no parameters and is returning an `NSInteger *`. In the implementation file you are defining a method that takes an `NSInteger **` and returns nothing (`void`). The version in the implementation file is closer to what you want.
2. NSInteger is not a class but a simple type. You do not have to pass it by reference like you do objects so you can just specify the parameter as `NSInteger` instead of `NSInteger *` or `NSInteger **`

That leaves you with this code in the header:

```
- (void)startProcess:(NSInteger)number;
```

and this code in the implementation file

```
- (void)startProcess:(NSInteger)number {
    [UITableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong here so I'll iterate through the ones I could catch first.

The first thing I noticed is that your definition for startProcess is horribly different than how its defined in your implementation.

Your header states it should return a pointer to an NSInteger and take no arguments, but your implementation says it should return nothing and take an NSInteger ** as an argument.

Furthermore, the reloadData method for UITableView is not a class method, it is an instance method. [UITableView reloadData] does not function because UITableView is a class, not an instance ( and you'd want to specify which tableView you'd want to refresh wouldn't you? )

As to answer the question, redefine your declaration in your impact.h file to be

```
-(void)startProcess:(NSInteger)tag;
```

and edit it's respected implementation to use an NSInteger as well.

I don't see why you'd need a pointer to a NSInteger.

Also, NSInteger as far as I remember is not an NSNumber, which means it's not an objective-c object. NSInteger is a typedef for a 'long'

```
typedef long NSInteger;
```